Smarter way of changing Evaluation Domain?
Is there another way of doing this? I want the length of each hair curve per point, but Blender calculates the length of each point based on the previous point rather than based on the length to the root point. What I'm doing here is using the accumulate field to sum the values of the lengths of the points and employing a hack to the index so that I repeat the ID of each point for an n number of resolutions of the splines. In other words, I repeat the accumulated length of the last point of each spline for the amount of points the splines have.
Is there another way of 'converting' one domain to another without resorting to a hack like this? In this case, input the total length of each spline to be the length of its individual points?

